AWS S3 sending notifications to an encrypted SNS topic
this is the scenario: I create in my AWS account S3 MyS3 and SNS topic MyTopic through Terraform scripts. MyS3 sends "object create" notifications to MyTopic.
Recently, a SAST/kics scan found an issue of type "SNS (Simple Notification Service) Topic should be encrypted" in the Terraform script that defines MyTopic.
I'm still testing, but it seems the issue is resolved by:

creating a custom managed key (MyKey); the policy is very permissive for now, I'll configure it later
initializing MyTopic kms_master_key_id with MyKey alias; after this change, the security issue disappears. As expected, the AWS console shows encryption enabled with MyKey's ARN
configuring MyS3 with "Server-side encryption with AWS Key Management Service keys (SSE-KMS)" and MyKey's ARN; the previous configuration was "Server-side encryption with Amazon S3 managed keys (SSE-S3)"

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, I appreciate your feedback.
Also, I have a doubt. I first configured MyTopic's encryption explicitly setting kms_master_key_id to the default "alias/aws/sns", but in this case I don't understand how to configure MyS3. Basically, it would be better if I can use the AWS managed keys instead of a customer managed key. Please, do you have any suggestions?

The simplest approach is using the AWS managed keys, just enable server-side encryption with aws-managed (default) keys on SNS and S3 (not sure how exactly and even if possible through the Terraform). That should work together.
As soon as you are using your own KMS, you will have to manage access to the clients, services, ...
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/grant-destinations-permissions-to-s3.html
